# Why am I still able to add any Object to a List with a raw-type reference type after changing its object type to a generic?

Tags: java, generics, reference, raw-types, object-type

I declared and initialized myList with a raw reference type of List and a raw object type of ArrayList. Then, I re-referenced myList to a new, generic ArrayList of Longs. I thought that adding anything other than a Long to this list would thus cause an error.

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
myList = new ArrayList<Long>();
myList.add(3.4d);
myList.add(4.0f);
myList.add("weird");
myList.add('w');
System.out.println(myList);
```

However, this runs without an error or exception. How is this legal?

Comment: The base type is raw even though you define the instance using generecity. When you call the add method your are calling the add method of a raw List. so from compile point of view everything is correct. On the other hand when the code is compiled there is no generics anymore, so from runtime point of view everything is correct.

Comment: That's how raw types work. However, **turn on warnings, and take heed of your compiler**.

Comment: Generics are entirely a _compile-time_ mechanism and don't exist at runtime, thus generics rely on the variable's compile-time type, not the "real type".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare it as `List<Long>` you will get static compile time type checking. Do to type erasure the JVM does not know anything about those types at runtime.

```
List<Long> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("foo");
```

Will give a compilation error while:

```
public void breakGeneric(List list) {
    list.add("foo");
}
....
List<Long> myList = new ArrayList<>();
breakGeneric(myList);
```

will add "foo" to a list no matter what type type is. Most IDEs will worn you about loosing the generic type.

Having the type in the new statement `new ArrayList<Long>()` would only have an effect if you chain off of that statement ie `new ArrayList<Long>().add("foo")`. That is the only way that a generic type *only* in the `new` statement will cause a compilation problem.

Answer (score 2):

How is this legal?

Because the java compiler only considers the *declared* type, which in this case is the raw type `List`:

```
List myList
```

that can hold any type of object.

The assignment `myList = new ArrayList<Long>()` has no effect on the declared type of `myList`.

Comment: It may be semantics, but this is not entirely true. Generics will effect anonymous objects with no type declaration. See my answer, though it is not a very useful edge case except maybe for the builder pattern.

Comment: @Seph no, it is entirely true.

Comment: This statement `new ArrayList<Long>().add("foo")` has no declared type, only inferred, yet will cause a compilation error.

Comment: @seph it *does* have a declared type, and it's *not* infered; the generic type of a `new ArrayList<Long>()` is hard coded as `Long`. An example of an in-line infered type would be `new ArrayList<>().add("");`, where `String` is the inferred type. However this point is not relevant to this question, which is about *raw* types.

Comment: Ahh, exactly why I started my comments with `it may be semantics`.